# How to write a member in Kotlin annotation?

Tags: java, kotlin, annotations

I have the next Java annotation:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@MapKey
@interface ViewModelKey {
    Class<? extends ViewModel> value();
}
```

To convert it in Kotlin annotation I have rewritten it as below:

```
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
@MapKey
annotation class ViewModelKey {
    fun value(): Class<out ViewModel> {}
}
```

But there is an error: `Members are not allowed in annotation class`.

**If members aren't allowed how can I convert Java annotation in Kotlin?**

Comment: Did you read [the documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/annotations.html#constructors)?

Comment: @LouisWasserman, yes, I have read it already but I couldn't get. I know how to use annotation but its implementation is hard for me still.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Kotlin you have to define properties and not functions in annotations:

```
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
@MapKey
annotation class ViewModelKey(val value: KClass<out ViewModel>)
```

See https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/annotations.html for details.

Comment: Have a look at the documentation for constructors: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#constructors

Comment: Thank you for answer, now it's clean for me.

Answer (score 1):

It might be a "KClass";

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@MapKey
internal annotation class ViewModelKey(val value: KClass<out ViewModel>)
```

https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-class/index.html

Comment: Thank you! Yes, `Class` doesn't work, there are used `KClass` in samples of the Kotlin annotation documentation.

Comment: I'm happy that it worked, this is my first positive return!!! Yay :) thank you too.